# Link against a 3rd-party library with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, libpq

I'm trying to create a .dll with Visual Studios 2013. The project includes libpq functionality.

Per other stackoverflow posts, and other sources I've found on the internet, I've (as far as I'm aware) correctly added the postgres lib and include directories to the project. However, when I go to build the project, it returns a number of "unresolved external symbol" errors.

My paths are `C:\Program Files\PostresSQL\9.3\...` so I have them surrounded by quotation marks in the Additional Library/Include Directory fields. I've included the `libpq-fe.h` header file in the project... I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Another note, I can compile a test program from the command line using g++ with the -I, -L, and -lpq flags, but I'm not sure how to compile to a .dll from the command line (plus it adds complexity that I just don't want to deal with).

These are the specific errors I'm getting:

```
1>sql_arma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQconnectdb
1>sql_arma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQstatus
1>sql_arma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQerrorMessage
1>sql_arma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _PQfinish
1>C:\Users\tills13\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\sql_arma\Release\sql_arma.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

I have, as suggested below, included `#pragma comment(lib, "libpq.lib")` in the source file for my project, I still receive these errors.

Comment: In order to build a DLL that depends on symbols from another DLL, I think you are supposed to export those symbols.
Maybe this could help you more:

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4zxe9k8.aspx

[2] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225432/export-all-symbols-when-creating-a-dll

[3] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx

Comment: I'm exporting the symbols that I need to in my code. My issue is with undefined symbols from libpq.

Comment: What about the linking configurations... are you linking against the correct .lib file? Silly question here: those unresolved external symbols are symbols from libpq, right?

Comment: @hbobenicio like I said in the post, I can compile it using the command line to an executable which works just fine using the same lib and include dirs

Comment: Have you checked the bitness 32/64 and/or the [runtime type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx)?

Comment: @TylerSebastian Can you post the exact linker errors ? This might help us understand the issue clearly. Just shooting in the dark though, are you linking to the correct runtime?

Comment: @s_b the exact errors, as I see them in the status window are "unresolved external symbol: <name of symbol>"

If it's available, I have not enabled verbose mode.

Comment: what's the linker's command line as printed in the build log? I'd like to see if it references the `libpq.lib`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've successfully compiled the [sample program](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq-example.html) by setting these project properties:

- Add `<pgsql install path>\include` and `\lib` to *VC++ Directories->Include* and *->Library*, correspondingly
- Add `libpq.lib` to *Linker->Input->Additional dependencies*

This is the standard way to reference 3rd-party libs. It's just that they recommend using environment variables for their "base dirs" to avoid patching the project when it's under a VCS.

- To be able to run the app from VS (both with and without debugging), I also specified `PATH=%PATH%;<pgsql install path>\bin` in *Debugging->Environment* since this dir isn't in `PATH` on my system.

Comment: Thank you. That adding `libpq.lib` to  Additional Dependencies did it. I wish I could have given you the bounty.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I have added pgsql path of include and lib dir in VC++ directories. Also added libpq.lib as an additional dependencies still I am seen linking issues as unresolved symbol. Code is compiling successfully but giving linking error.

Comment: @void It's impossible to tell without seeing more info. Ask another question mentioning you did as this one specifies and provide related settings and output.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: I could able to solve linking issue. I was using 64 bit postgres installer as I have 64bit OS when I replaced 64bit version with 32bit. I was able to run the sample code successfully. I am not sure why it was giving me linking errors for 64 bit installer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient add the postgres lib directory to the project, you must also add
reference to `libpq.lib`. Just add this line to one of your source `.cpp` files:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libpq.lib")
```

As noted by *Marco A.* the library must match a program bitness (32 or 64 bit): if you build 32-bit DLL (referred as `Win32`) you must use 32 bit library; if 64-bit (`x64`) - 64-bit library.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not working. I have edited my post with more information.

Comment: I am currently reinstalling 32bit postgres to see if that will solve the issue.

Comment: No-go. 32bit and 64bit postgres produce the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same issue. Then I realized that I was building my application as a 32bit. I changed the target of my application to x64 and it compiled successfully

[image]