# How can I use Python.h file to make python C extensions

Tags: python, c, visual-studio, extension-methods

I want to make c extension for python. I know basics of C, and i want to make extensions because of better performance. I dont know Visual Studio and C very well. So please be considerate.

I searched to much but i didnt find any working solution. When i am trying to 
`#include <Python.h>`
file, it is saying it cant find it. What should i do?

Comment: Locate Python.h on your computer, then add its directory to your include search path.

Comment: I have a Python.h file in python\include. Are they same? And I tried to add python\include to my include search path

Answer (score 1):

MS has a document dedicated to your exact case, with step-by-step instructions: [Write C++ extensions for Python - Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

In brief, you

- Create a C++ DLL project
- link it against `pythonXY.dll` as per [Link against a 3rd-party library with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611998/link-against-a-3rd-party-library-with-visual-studio)
- specify some Python-specific settings:

  - `.pyd` extension
  - a version of MSVC toolchain corresponding to your Python version as per https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers
- Create a Python project and support `.py` files in it, e.g. `setup.py`
- Reference the C++ project from the Python project. That will build the `.pyd` before running the Python project and make it available for Python code in it.

Note that there's no further integration with distutils, pytest, tox and whatnot.