# some SDL linking problems

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sdl-2

so here's the problem I'm having. All of a sudden, implementing SDL just doesn't work anymore on vs 2013. To be more specific, anytime include the SDL standard header I get linker errors. I tried building my project with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_GLContext context;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING)){
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL&SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    }
    SDL_Delay(20000);
    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:

1. Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_CreateWindow referenced in function _SDL_main    C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
2. Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_DestroyWindow referenced in function _SDL_main   C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
3. Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GL_SetAttribute referenced in function _SDL_main C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
4. Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GL_CreateContext referenced in function _SDL_main    C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
5. Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_GL_DeleteContext referenced in function _SDL_main    C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
6. Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Delay referenced in function _SDL_main   C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
7. Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init referenced in function _SDL_main    C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\main.obj
8. Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup   C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Open GL\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
9. Error   9   error LNK1120: 8 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Nas\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Open GL\Debug\Open GL.exe

any help is appreciated :)

here's a list of things I already tried:

1. undefining main ~> #undef main
2. changing my subsystem to both windows and console (neither worked)
3. Repeatedly cleaning and rebuilding my project.

Comment: where are you specifying the static SDL library to be linked with your project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you link against the SDL.dll?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212492/how-do-you-add-external-libraries-for-compilation-in-vc) is explained how you do that.

Cheers,
lindebear

Comment: Well, basically when you're using `LoadLibrary` you are linking... that's what DLL stands for DLL -> Dynamic Link Library. :D

Comment: For the record I know what DLL stands for, and I know the difference between a statically linked library and a dynamically linked one. Yet, for some reason I was still stupid enough to forget to link the DLL. Thanks for helping me with this stupid blunder, really appreciate it :).

Comment: Well in that case I apologize for telling you again! haha :D